# Нарисовать круг средствами html4/js (без явного css)

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть такая интересная задача - нарисовать круг средствами html и js. По сути, задача сводится к созданию div на разметке определенной ширины/высоты. Саму методику я могу предложить т.к. есть способ рисовать например ромб

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('container');
var tmp, k = 0,
  m = 200;
for (var i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
  if (i > m / 2) k--;
  else k++;
  tmp = document.createElement('div');
  //tmp.style.border = '1px solid #111fff'
  tmp.style.width = k + 'px';
  tmp.style.height = '1px';
  obj.appendChild(tmp);
}
```

```css
#container
{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container div
{
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Но я хотел бы попросить помощи в алгоритме рисования подобным образом круга. Как правильно составить алгоритм, который построчно нарисует круг с помощью дивов?
Я пытался сделать при помощи формулы c = 2R*sin(angle/2), где с - это расстояние между точками на окружности, а angle - это угол в радианах. Но получается капля, а не круг. 
Код "капли":

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('container1');
var tmp, k = 0,
  m = 300,
  angl = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
  if (angl > 360) angl = 360;
  tmp = document.createElement('div');
  var sinus = Math.sin((Math.PI * angl / 180) / 2);
  tmp.style.width = m * sinus + 'px';

  tmp.style.height = '1px';
  obj.appendChild(tmp);
  var nexAngle = 360 / m;
  angl += nexAngle;
}
```

```css
#container,
#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container1 div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

P.S  код очень некрасивый т.к. делалось "в лоб" )

UPD: @pavel и  @Gleb Kemarsky оба ответили на поставленный вопрос, просто немного разными способами (хоть в итоге все сводится к одной формуле). За реализацию на JQuery спасибо @Elena Semenchenko! @sitev_ru тоже спасибо! Поэтому заинтересованным советую обратить внимание на все ответы данного вопроса. Спасибо !

Comment: А почему именно html4 и div, а не html5 и canvas?

Comment: @andreymal Потому что так интересней! Задача на "немного подумать". С канвасом все решается без проблем. Просто у меня не хватило своих мозгов додуматься до такого, вот и решил создать вопрос

Comment: Кстати, а почему Math.sin((Math.PI * angl / 180) / 2), если, вроде, 180/pi * angl,

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, вроде как была формула переводу угла в радианы. Как то так `Ar = Ad * пи / 180`
Где Ad — угол в градусах, Ar — угол в радианах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, лучше не через угол, а через отрезки.

Задаём радиус. Проходим круг по вертикали и рисуем хорды. Половина от длины хорды - корень квадратный из разницы между квадратом радиуса и квадратом "высоты" хорды.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('container1');
var tmp, 
  radius = 200;
for (var i = 0; i <= 2 * radius; i++) {
  var height = Math.abs(radius - i);
  var chord = 2 * Math.sqrt(radius * radius - height * height);
  tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.style.height = '1px';
  tmp.style.width = chord + 'px';
  obj.appendChild(tmp);
}
```

```css
#container1 div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вот только вопрос - я по сути пытался сделать тоже самое, но через углы. Может вы заметили мою ошибку в коде ?

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать точно так же на jQuery, а получается четвертинка)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko буду благодарен если вы поделитесь кодом на Jquery ) Сейчас попробую тоже сделать. Заодно еще и по узнаем как эту задачку на jquery "рисовать" =)

Comment: @alexoander 1) Теорема Пифагора помогает решить задачу более простыми вычислениями, и тем самым спасает от потерь времени на поиск ошибок. 2) Мне кажется, нельзя делать цикл по всем 360 градусам, потому что в построении круга участвуют далеко не все углы. Думаю, надо идти всё по тому же вертикальному диаметру и для каждого очередного блока вычислять его угол. А потом для этого угла рассчитывать длину блока. Моя гипотеза: капля получилась именно из-за прохождения по всем углам подряд.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky хм вы так убедительны, что я с вами соглашусь! Но проверю и попытаюсь опровергнуть =) Спасибо!

Comment: @alexoander Можно попробовать для каждого угла вычислять высоту блока. Сейчас они все по `1px`, а по идее высота блока у горизонтального диаметра должна быть больше высоты блока у верхней или нижней макушки круга. Но блоки у макушек круга будут уж очень низенькие. Поэтому боюсь, что на этом пути вмешается погрешность округления результата, и круг снова получится искажённым.

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так, точную константу вместо 5 подобрать вручную думаю проще.

Идея формулы: у нас есть треугольник (равносторонний, высота - (50 - k) пикселей,  стороны по 50 пикселей (радиус круга)). Отсюда из теоремы Пифагора его ширина = 2*Sqrt( 50*50 - (50-k)*(50-k) ). Но если так сделать то его сильно сожмёт (из-за границ возможно), поэтому нужно домножать на коэффициент.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('container');
var tmp, k = 0,
  m = 100;
for (var i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
  if (i > m / 2) k--;
  else k++;
  tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.style.border = '1px solid #111fff'
  tmp.style.width = 5*Math.sqrt(50*50 - (50-k)*(50-k)) + 'px';
  tmp.style.height = '1px';
  obj.appendChild(tmp);
}
```

```css
#container
{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container div
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Если не затруднит - можете описать формулу (типа C= 2*pi*R^2) ? Просто даже как-то грустно мне не знать геометрию

Comment: @alexoander обновил ответ, если всё равно непонятно, пишите.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень ясно и понятно (хотя пришлось немного порисовать, чтобы осознать как эта формула работает).

Comment: Правда появился вопрос - а почему вы "интерпретировали" действия над окружностью на равносторонний треугольник? Я пытаюсь понять ход мыслей, чтобы научиться мыслить в данном направлении

Comment: @alexoander http://joxi.ru/nAy936niXo35bA как-то так

Answer (score 1):

На jQuery, по формуле окружности получилось вот такое:

```js
function arc(r){
  $('<div>',{
    class: 'box'
  }).appendTo('body');
  
  for(var i = 0; i <= 2*r; i++ ){
    
      var y = Math.abs(r - i);
      var x = 2*Math.sqrt( Math.pow(r,2) - Math.pow(y,2) );
    
      $('<i>',{
        class: 'i'
      })
      .css({
        'display': 'block', 
        'width': x + 'px', 
        'height': '1px', 
        'background-color':'lightgreen',
        'margin-left': 'auto',
        'margin-right': 'auto'
      })
      .appendTo('.box');
  }
}

arc(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну формула все равно схожая - хоть и отталкивается от координатной сетки.У меня тоже что-то схожее получилось - правда не так красиво и компактно как у вас. Спасибо за исследования)

Answer (score 0):

как-то так:

```
r = 100; //radius
for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
  x = r * cos(i);
  y = r * sin(i);
}
```

по координатам x,y рисуешь круг...

Но в задании нужно рисовать дивами, переделал свой метод... Вот что получилось:

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('container1');
var tmp, radius = 200, ys = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
  var x = Math.sin(Math.PI * i / 180) * radius * 2;
  var y = radius - Math.cos(Math.PI * i / 180) * radius;
  var h = y;
  if (i != 0) h = y - ys;
  ys = y;
  tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.style.height = h + 'px';
  tmp.style.width = x + 'px';
  obj.appendChild(tmp);
}
```

```css
#container1 div {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: Такая формула хороша, но тут немного "другие" правила т.к. мне нужно отрисовать круг "построчно" рисуя каждый див. а координаты это каждая точка - немного другой способ.

Comment: переделал... может и сойдёт)

Comment: Главное работает) А можете пояснить, почему такое странное ограничение в цикле ? Радиус то 200 , а ограничение 180 ? Также строка с if( i!=0 ) немного смущает (условие не срабатывает только 1 раз). В остальном согласен, спасибо!